# Get first entered value in textbox using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have one textbox and one optionsmenu as follows:

```
<form>
<input type="text" id="input" size="20" onchange="func()">
<select id="no" >
<option>Options</option>
<option>Acre</option>   
<option>Ares</option>
<option>Cent</option>   
<option>m^2</option>
<option>ft^2</option>   
</select>
</form>
```

I want to store the very first value entered in the textbox. As I call onchange and result is displayed on the same input textbox,the values changes. Is there anyway to store the first value

Comment: Sorry but I don't get your question. You want to to store - the first value entered in the textbox - , or do you want to store - the first value ( probably of the select ) - into the textbox ?

Comment: Where (server or client) do you want to store the information? And for how long (until reload, for the session, etc)?

Comment: I just want the value for further calculation,like if I type 100 and select one option result is 10 and is set to input box, now the input value become 10. I want the 100 or the variable for all further calculations

Comment: Store it in a javascript variable on the first `onchange` event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi the following code will help you

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var firstValue = "";

    function func() {
      if (firstValue == "") {
        firstValue = document.getElementById("input").value;
      }
      var currentValue = document.getElementById("input").value;
      alert("First Value is " + firstValue + " and Current Value is " + currentValue);
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <input type="text" id="input" size="20" onchange="func()">
    <select id="no">
      <option>Options</option>
      <option>Acre</option>
      <option>Ares</option>
      <option>Cent</option>
      <option>m^2</option>
      <option>ft^2</option>
    </select>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```